# Decimals (involuntarily) trimmed from values when loaded into environment

Tags: r

I'm working with R 3.6.1 in Rstudio 1.2.1335.

When I assign the following value from a column in my data frame, the values that have decimals in that column in the dataframe, get trimmed in the value I assign:

Dataframe$Column1 has values [368.121 376.436]

Value <-- Dataframe$Column1

And I run my code chunk;
The environment shows the column values as: Value num [1:2] 368 376
My decimals have gone and I need those. Why does this happen and is there a way to fix it?

EDIT:

Set_1.

```
380.283 332.108 327.405 371.570 325.832 345.583 396.377 367.020 428.980 389.524 379.597 407.483 456.271 312.084 391.198 345.813 406.229 346.450 459.307 392.321 337.638 429.377 353.705 377.512 384.921 346.471 411.855 368.406 386.921 397.797 322.416 412.042 383.240 381.244 440.021 372.444 399.301 345.395 359.865 355.449 314.270 453.173 329.055 299.674 351.675 324.334 425.205 437.013 513.334 436.452 335.658 422.669 300.030 287.893 380.611 297.890 351.203 317.065 350.824 269.149 389.509 467.375 399.065 354.954 465.086 353.615 336.454 372.067 424.167 389.172 357.799 321.663 353.633 388.465 342.489 353.487 398.721 416.194 383.376 355.553 398.667 339.722 316.240 383.894 453.429 351.443 460.038 348.860 304.085 258.921
264.107 241.861 278.548 455.216 393.201 348.211 359.426 427.194 391.599 381.335 340.558 369.617 351.342 318.718 338.960 386.547 388.872 283.943 340.501
```

Set_2:

```
380.603 332.100 327.391 371.540 325.826 345.602 396.386 367.029 428.949 389.545 379.584 407.454 456.276 312.093 391.414 345.861 406.235 346.259 459.284 392.334 337.626 429.283 353.539 377.568 384.941 346.491 411.820 368.253 386.816 397.723 322.337 412.020 383.158 381.331 440.066 372.361 399.210 345.438 359.948 355.425 314.271 453.169 328.751 299.701 351.388 324.371 425.219 436.906 513.384 436.475 335.508 422.661 300.036 287.908 380.453 297.306 351.275 317.206 351.165 269.122 389.499 467.402 399.136 354.943 465.057 353.593 336.549 372.079 424.062 389.119 357.753 321.758 353.650 388.599 342.285 353.507 398.682 416.289 383.309 355.456 398.816 339.681 316.273 383.898 453.418 351.395 460.027 348.731 304.111 258.452
264.298 241.829 278.297 455.104 393.228 348.117 359.645 427.096 391.526 381.260 340.474 369.791 351.061 318.780 338.949 386.458 389.030 284.093 340.512
```

Code:

```
plot(Set_1,Set_2,col = "red", xlab="Set_1", ylab = "Set_2", 
     main = "Comparison Set_1 and Set_2", type = 'p')
abline(fit5<-lm(Set_2~Set_1), col="blue")
r5<-round(summary(fit5)$adj.r.square, 4)
text(410,330, paste("R2=",r5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimals aren't gone, they are just not shown in your enviroment. Try accessing the values by `Value[1]`. This clearly gives you your desired result `368.121`.

Comment: I have been able to do that, but the rub is when I refer to Value and Value2 in a plot (for example) and I want to calculate R2, I get R2=1, which is impossible. It can be very close to 1, but it can never be 1, unless it uses trimmed values, since the trimmed values of Value1 and Value2 are exactly the same.

Comment: Can you provide an example for that behavior by showing some data and code? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: I have found the crux. The R2 had four decimals, but the results were so close I needed at least 6 decimals to see that it wasn't 1. I incorrectly deduced that this was due to what the Rstudio environment told me. I will mark your answer as the solution.